# python 3.2 - find second smallest number in a list using recursion

Tags: python, recursion, python-3.2

So I need to find the second smallest number within a list of integers using recursion but I cannot for the life of me devise a way to do it. I can do it with to find smallest number using this:

```
def smallest(int_list):

    if(len(int_list) == 1):
        return int_list[0]
    else:
        a = smallest(int_list[1:])
        b = int_list[0]

        if(a <= b):
            return a
        else:
            return b
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Create 2 functions, one that finds the smallest and one that tries to find the next smallest given the return value of the first function

Comment: Instead of returning just the smallest, try returning a tuple that contains the smallest and second smallest of the part of the list you've processed so far. Keep updating the tuple at each step.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect describes the matter pretty well.

Comment: check my answer, I implemented something like @shridharama suggested.

Comment: One thing is not very clear, do you want to return 2nd smallest even elements are duplicate like return `1` in `[1,1,2,3]`? Or you want `2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short implementation that doesn't use `min()` or `sorted()`. It also works when there are duplicate values in the list.

```
def ss(e):
    if len(e)==2 and e[0]<=e[1]:return e[1]
    return ss(e[:-1]) if e[0]<=e[-1]>=e[1] else ss([e[-1]]+e[:-1])

print("The selected value was:", ss([5, 4, 3, 2, 1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. get_smallest_two_items() returns a tuple with the smallest 2 elements out of the 3 inputted. Implementing it should be trivial. Also note that this assumes the minimum length of the list is 2.

```
def smallest(int_list):
   smallest_two = smallest_helper(int_list)
   return smallest_two[0] if smallest_two[0]<=smallest_two[1] else smallest_two[1]

def smallest_helper(int_list):

  if(len(int_list) == 2):
    return (int_list[0],int_list[1])
  else:
    a_b = smallest(int_list[1:])
    a = a_b[0]
    b = a_b[1]
    c = int_list[0]

    return get_smallest_two_items(a,b,c)
```

Comment: Umm. Mind commenting before down-voting?

Comment: sure, where does that `get_smallest_two_items(a,b,c)` come from?

Comment: @Anzel How exactly? It returns the smallest out of a, b and c as a tuple as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: have you even tested your code? you have no where named a function called `get_smallest_two_items()`... it is a **NameError**

Comment: I've mentioned in the answer that the method should be easy to implement. My aim was not to write perfectly executable code, it was more to point OP in the right direction. Stackoverflow is not meant for spoon-feeding every single line of code.

Comment: ok, you have a valid point but weak, you're using mutually recursive functions which itself doesn't really explain much nor give any clear direction. I'll withdraw the downvote, for once

Answer (score 0):

Simpler example than my comment:

```
def find_nth_smallest(n, int_list):
    smallest = min(int_list)
    if n <= 1:
        return smallest
    int_list = [v for v in int_list if v != smallest]
    if int_list:
        return max(find_nth_smallest(n - 1, int_list), smallest)
    return None
```

Example:

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Oct 20 2014, 15:05:19) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from kthTerm import find_nth_smallest
>>> import random
>>> random.seed()
>>> int_list = [random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(20)]
>>> int_list
[68, 50, 6, 36, 98, 15, 81, 36, 13, 71, 76, 77, 69, 75, 79, 53, 26, 25, 18, 62]
>>> find_nth_smallest(2, int_list)
13
>>> sorted(int_list)
[6, 13, 15, 18, 25, 26, 36, 36, 50, 53, 62, 68, 69, 71, 75, 76, 77, 79, 81, 98]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
def r_sort(a_list, ind):
    def rf(list_to_be_sorted, list_already_sorted):
        li = []
        if len(list_to_be_sorted) == 0:
            return list_already_sorted
        else:    
            x = min(list_to_be_sorted)    
            list_to_be_sorted.remove(x)
            li.append(x)
            return rf(list_to_be_sorted, list_already_sorted + li)
    return rf(a_list, [])[ind]

>>> r_sort([1,10,9,5,55,3,2], 1)  
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that doesn't blow the stack for large lists. It would be better to manage the search endpoints manually rather than using slicing which introduce copying.

```
import random

def min2(xs):
    if len(xs) < 3: return xs
    n = len(xs) // 2
    return sorted(min2(xs[:n]) + [xs[n]] + min2(xs[n+1:]))[:2]

tk = range(100000)
random.shuffle(tk)
print min2(tk)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure recursive way. You need to return the first smallest and the second smallest element in a tuple and so on.

```
def smallest(int_list):

    if(len(int_list) == 2):
        if (int_list[0] >= int_list[1]):
            return (int_list[0],int_list[1])
        else:
            return (int_list[1],int_list[0])
    else:
        first_smallest,second_smallest = smallest(int_list[1:])
        current_elem = int_list[0]
        if(second_smallest <= current_elem):
            return (second_smallest,current_elem)
        else:
            if (current_elem<=first_smallest):
               return (current_elem,first_smallest)
            else:
               return (first_smallest,second_smallest)



if __name__ == "__main__":    
    small = smallest([1,2,3,4])
    print small[1]
    //output 2
```

Comment: smallest([2,1,3,4,5]) should return 2. This returns (1, 3).

Answer (score -2):

def second_smallest(my_list):

```
if len(my_list) == 2:
    return my_list[0] if my_list[0] > my_list[1] else my_list[1]

else:
    sec_least = second_smallest(my_list[1:])
    return sec_least if sec_least < my_list[0] else my_list[1]
```

Comment: second_smallest([2,1,3,4,5]) returns 1, but should return 2. 

second_smallest([1,1,2,3,4]) returns 2, but should return 1.